# Complexity of (Graph) Ramsey Theorem in Sum-of-Squares Proof System

Tags: reference-request, sum-of-squares, ramsey-theory

(One formulation of) [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) states that any colouring of edges of the complete graph with $4^n$ vertices with two colours will contain a monochromatic clique of size $n$. I am new to proof complexity and what interests me is the complexity of proving the *upper bound* using the [sum-of-squares](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14400/sum-of-squares-proof-system?rq=1) proof system. Do we know any upper bound or degree lower bounds for this question?

A related question is: which is the weakest proof system in which we know that Ramsey's theorem is provable? I am aware of a result due to Pudlák [P] which shows that this is possible in bounded arithmetic (i.e., $S_2$ and then shown by Jeřábek [J] to be $T_2^3$ precisely). Do we know of anything weaker?

[P]: Pudlák, *[Ramsey's theorem in bounded arithmetic](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-54487-9_67)*, CSL 1990

[J]: Jeřábek, *[Approximate counting by hashing in bounded arithmetic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/approximate-counting-by-hashing-in-bounded-arithmetic/A9694B6029ED684543A15FEFCEC9F610)*, Journal of Symbolic Logic, 2009

Comment: As for bounded arithmetic, I believe nothing better than $T^1_2+\mathit{rWPHP}(PV_2)$ (which is included in $T^3_2$) is known. As for propositional proof systems, lower bounds are known for resolution (see Lauria, Pudlák, Rödl, Thapen: The complexity of proving that a graph is Ramsey) and cutting planes (Lauria: A rank lower bound for cutting planes proofs of Ramsey's theorem); I don’t know if there are any SoS lower bounds.

Comment: Thanks, Emil. I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: I suppose by $rWPHP$ you are referring to relational $WPHP$?

Comment: No, retraction-pair WPHP, as in my paper that you linked to.